# Как проверить размер загружаемого файла в Nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

Как увеличить допустимы размер я знаю:

> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {
    #...
        client_max_body_size 30m;
    #...
}
```

А вот как сделать редирект самим **Nginx** на страницу при больших отправленных данных - не знаю.

Теоретически предполагаю, что на Flask можно прописать:

```
@app.errorhandler(413)
def not_found_error(error):
    return render_template('413.html'), 413
```

Но это тогда получается, что если несколько приложений развернуто - то надо каждому прописывать, а вот как сделать, чтобы **Nginx** не пускал на приложения уже такой объем данных или этого нельзя сделать?

---

---

### Дополнение:

Почитал руководство, которое посоветовал @andreymal. Плюс нашел еще [мануал](https://www.8host.com/blog/nastrojka-polzovatelskix-stranic-oshibok-nginx-v-centos-7/)

Залил файл **413.html** в каталог:

> /usr/share/nginx/html

Зашел в настройки файла:

> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Внес изменения в конце (это последняя запись):

```
http{
...
server {
     error_page 413 /413.html;
     location = /413.html {
                            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                            internal;
                           }
       }
}
```

В итоге эта ошибка не отрабатывает. Но, если сделать эти изменения в настройках приложения **APP** (APP.servise), то тогда страница ошибки откроется...

Но это не *камельфо*, т.к. получается что надо будет для каждого приложения прописывать такие настройки (либо с таким же успехом можно прописать эти ошибки в самих приложениях)...

Что не так? Может, где-то идет переопределение моих настроек?

Comment: Через опцию [error_page](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) можно сделать внутреннее перенаправление на любую угодную страницу (в том числе во Flask, данные туда передаваться не будут)

Comment: @andreymal, ок, спасибо. Попробую.

Comment: Ну, если вы прописали `error_page` в отдельной секции server, то вполне логично, что оно работает только для этой конкретной секции, а не для секции с приложением

Comment: «надо будет для каждого приложения прописывать» — пропишите, в чём проблема?

Comment: @andreymal, но это же получается дублирование.... Я же сначала прописал для файла **nginx.conf** - он же главный. получается, что должно было примениться для всех. Или не так?

Comment: Настройки, прописанные в секции server, действуют только для этой самой секции server. Расположение файлов не имеет никакого значения

Comment: Если вам не нравится дублирование, вы всегда можете вынести дублирующийся кусок настроек в отдельный файл и подключать его в нужных секциях server через [include](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include)

Comment: @andreymal, тогда почему, когда я прописываю размер загружаемых данных в файле **nginx.conf ** и это применяется для всех приложений (на сколько я понимаю это происходит потому, что внутри блока **nginx.conf **  подключаются настройки приложений через **include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;  **)

Comment: Потому что вы прописываете его не в секции server, а в секции http, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal, я же в дополнении указал, что настройки прописываю тоже в файле **nginx.conf** в разделе **http**

Comment: Вы в дополнении указали, что вы создали новую секцию server и прописали в ней error_page, вот он и действует только на эту конкретную секцию server, а не на ваше приложение, которое находится в какой-то другой секции server

Comment: Но если писать без секции **server** - то nginx не запустится. Скажет что ошибка там

Comment: Потому что location можно прописывать только в секциях server — вот и пропишите его в секции server вашего приложения

Comment: Получается, что правильное решение это прописать настройки в отдельный файл и потом их подключать через **include** ко всем приложениям в разделе **server**?

Comment: Насчёт «правильного» не знаю (наверное, это субъективно), но я так делаю на своих серверах и мне норм

Comment: @andreymal, почитал еще сторонние ресурсы. По ходу действительно - через подключение это действительно единственный способ. Вопрос такой. Как будет правильно создать подключение: создать папку , например **my_settings** в каталоге **/etc/nginx** и там создать файл **my_conf.conf** туда прописать настройки и потом подключить через **include** во все *app.servise* всех приложений или рекомендуется создавать папку в другом месте?

Comment: Не знаю как у вас, но в некоторых стандартных установках nginx для этого обычно уже существует папочка `snippets`

Comment: @andreymal, папка есть. Значит лучше там настройки сохранять?(как это общепринято)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Выражаю благодарность [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) в помощи решения этого вопроса.**

Оставлю решение, если кто тоже столкнётся в будущем.

**1. Создается НТML-файлы с ошибками.**

**2. Заливаются на сервер** (я залил через **scp**):

```
scp URL_LOCAL_FILE SSH_USER@IP_SERVER:URL_SERV_DIR
```

URL_LOCAL_FILE  - расположение файла локально
URL_SERV_DIR - расположение папки на сервере (Абсолютный путь).

Абсолютный путь можно узнать через команду:

```
echo $PWD
```

**3. Создается папка с пользовательскими настройками.** Я создал в:

> /etc/nginx/snippets
> **4. Создается файл с ошибками, например: NAME_FILE:**

```
sudo nano NAME_FILE.conf
```

**5. Там прописываем настройки ([примеры других настроек](https://onedev.net/post/634)):**

```
error_page 413 /413.html;

location = /413.html {
                      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                      internal;
                     }
```

**6. Добавляем в блок **server** конфига приложения:**

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/APP_CONF

```
server {
...
include /etc/nginx/snippets/NAME_FILE.conf
}
```

---

Пункт №6 - применяется для всех конфигов приложений на сервере, если
хотите, чтобы страница ошибки была одинаковая на всех приложениях.

7. Чтобы применились настройки - надо не забыть перезагрузить **nginx**:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```